# replace columns in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have created a table in hive, now I am trying to replace the columns name using **REPLACE COLUMNS**.
Alter query is:

```
**ALTER TABLE emp1 REPLACE COLUMNS (
id INT eid int,
name STRING ename string,
sal INT esal int,
city string ecity string,
country string ecountry string);**
```

MismatchedTokenException(26!=301)
    at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.recoverFromMismatchedToken(BaseRecognizer.java:617)
    at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(BaseRecognizer.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.alterStatementSuffixAddCol(HiveParser.java:9898)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.alterTblPartitionStatementSuffix(HiveParser.java:8524)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.alterTableStatementSuffix(HiveParser.java:8139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.alterStatement(HiveParser.java:7190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1065)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:775)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:628)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 2:7 mismatched input 'eid' expecting ) near 'INT' in add column statement

Please help me. I am learning hive

Answer (score 2):

REPLACE is used when you want to have an altogether different columns to your table.If not it is better to rename the column_name with the CHANGE option in the alter statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `ALTER TABLE <TableName> REPLACE COLUMNS` removes all existing columns and adds the new set of columns.

`ALTER TABLE <TableName> REPLACE COLUMNS
(EID INT,
EName STRING);`

[REPLACE COLUMNS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Add/ReplaceColumns)

For your scenario you can make use of `ALTER TABLE <TableName> CHANGE <ColumnName>`

`ALTER TABLE <TableName> CHANGE ID EID INT;`

This page will give you a lots of information [ALTER COLUMNS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterColumn)